# How do you set a textfields text?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nstextfield

I was wondering how do you set a textfields text in XCode Objective - C.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE, objective-c is a language. Are you developing for iOS or OS X?

Answer (score 4):

```
[myTextField setStringValue: @"a string or an NSString object"];
```

Comment: That's not the right method.

Comment: It didnt work, just did nothing, could you give an example?

Comment: @HamishClaxton Have you connected to the outlet to .h file with outlet named myTextField ?

Comment: Im working on OSX not for iOS.

Comment: How do you connect them?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Sorry, my comment was based on iOS. Now that we know the question is about OS X - I don't know.

Comment: if you r using xcode4, ctrl+drag from NSTextField to ur appdeletage (the default one) and give outlet name myTextField. It will connect.

Comment: Oh ok, So that will work for OS X?

Comment: or read some tutorials, its very easy...

Comment: I have tried to find as much information as I can, still don't really get it.

Comment: read Aaron Hillegas book on cocoa, or u can find so many videos on youtube or lynda's check them

Comment: setStringValue: is the way to do it. You should make sure your outlet is being set properly. (In the debugger, make sure your textfield variable is not null.)

Comment: Ok, how do I make sure my outlet is being set properly